# fabricjs (Canvas). How to make more solid text glow?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How can i make more solid text glow (shadow) to look like on screenshot at right side?
Settings with rgba(255,255,255,1) 0 0 20px doesn't give needed effect, only small white glow...
Any another ways to make it?
[image]

Comment: Draw it twice, or 3 times over itself. vary the amount of shadow blur between renders to change the blur fall off

Comment: @Blindman67 How i can draw it with canvas js?

Comment: Ditto @Blindman67's comment about double/triple overdraws. To answer you comment: You can make `Fabric.Image`s containing your  glowing bumper phrases ("Just Sold",etc). Create an in-memory canvas with  `document.createElement('canvas'). Draw your bumper phrase on the in-memory canvas. Create a Fabric.Image using `inMemCanvas.toDataURL` as the `image` source. BTW, when calculate the text width using `context.measureText` -- be sure to allow for the blur (shadowing is not included in the `measureText` calculation).